# Error in this bash script

Tags: bash

I want to make a build chain script, and I don't want it to perform until the end if there are error during compilation.

It's the first time I write a more "elaborated" script in bash, and it just doesn't work:

1. it doesn't echo ERROR although I have lines with the word error in it
2. whatever the value of testError, the script just hangs in the line

this is the code:

```
testError=false

output=$(scons)
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == .*[eE]rror.* ]] ; then echo 'ERROR' ; $testError = true ; fi #$testError = true fi
done

echo $testError
if  $testError  ; then exit ; fi;

... other commands
```

**EDIT:** Following all posters answers and [Bash setting a global variable inside a loop and retaining its value -- Or process substituion for dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012841/bash-setting-a-global-variable-inside-a-loop-and-retaining-its-value-or-proce) and [How do I use regular expressions in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts),
this is the final version of the code.
It works:

```
testError=false

shopt -s lastpipe
scons | while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ .*[eE]rror.* ]] ; then
    echo -e 'ERROR' 
    testError=true 
  fi 
  echo -e '.'
done

if  $testError  ; then
    set -e 
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the value of `testError` in a subshell induced by your pipeline. When that subshell exits (at the end of the pipeline), any changes you made disappear. Try this:

```
while read -r line; do
   if [[ $line == .*[eE]rror.* ]] ; then
     echo -e 'ERROR' 
     testError=true 
   fi #$testError = true fi
done < <( scons )
```

or, if you don't want or can't use process substitution, use a temporary file

```
scons > tmp
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line == .*[eE]rror.* ]] ; then
    echo -e 'ERROR' 
    testError=true 
  fi #$testError = true fi
done < tmp
```

This eliminates the pipeline, so the changes to `testError` persist after the while loop.

And, if your version of bash is new enough (4.2 or later), there is an option that allows the while loop at the end of a pipeline to execute in the current shell, not a subshell.

```
shopt -s lastpipe
scons | while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line == .*[eE]rror.* ]] ; then
    echo -e 'ERROR' 
    testError=true 
  fi #$testError = true fi
done
```

Comment: if have version 4.2.24, that might do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
set -e
```

this stops the script to continue if a command exit with a non zero status

or better

```
error_case() { # do something special; }
trap 'echo >&2 "an error occurs"; error_case' ERR
```

this run `error_case` function each time a command exit with a non zero status

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to parse the output of scons?

This:

```
output=$(scons)
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == .*[eE]rror.* ]] ; then 
        echo 'ERROR' 
        testError=true
    fi
done
```

does not do that.  Perhaps you want:

```
scons | while read -r line; do ... ; done
```

Comment: The pipeline creates a subshell where changes to `testError` are no longer global.

Comment: @chepner I'm reading this question, related to what you're pointing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012841/bash-setting-a-global-variable-inside-a-loop-and-retaining-its-value-or-proce

Comment: @chepner testError does not need to be global; it only needs to be referenced within the loop.

Comment: No, he is explicitly testing the value *outside* the loop.

Comment: @chepner  But he should not be!  The code can be simplified substantially, and this answer is merely intended to point out his major error: namely that he was not parsing the output of scons.

Answer (score 1):

Another bug is that you have spaces in the assignment. And skip the `$`

```
$testError = true
```

should be

```
testError=true
```

*EDIT*

testerror is changed in the subshell. Try

```
testerror=$(
    scons | while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == .*[eE]rror.* ]] ; then
            echo true 
        fi #$testError = true fi
    done
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer also because other answers didn't notice: the use of regular expression should be done this way, using `=~`and not `==`:

```
if [[ $line =~ .*[eE]rror.* ]] ; then
...
```

cf [How do I use regular expressions in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts)