# Global variable is reset if loop send output to pipe

Tags: bash, variables, loops, subshell

According the bash(1) man pages, when I run the following:

```
set -e
x=2
echo Start $x
while [ $((x--)) -gt 0 ]; do echo Loop $x; done | cat
echo End $x
```

The output will be:

```
Start 2
Loop 1
Loop 0
End 2
```

After the loop (runs as a subshell) the variable x reset to 2.   But if I remove the pipe the x will be updated:

```
Start 2
Loop 1
Loop 0
End -1
```

I need to change the x but, I need the pipe too. 
Any idea how to get around this problem?

Comment: What does `| cat` do here?  Does it do something meaningful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4667509/900873

Comment: @devnull, I think it's just there for illustration: that adding a pipe to anything will mean the while loop is run in a subshell, and any changes to variable $x are lost when the subshell ends.

Comment: Yes, The real loop is long.  Inside the loop I have some lines like:  ping -c1 Machine || STOP="YES"      At the end of the loop I grep(1) out the lines of "icmp_seq="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` always (at least as of 4.2) runs all non-rightmost parts of a pipeline in a subshell. If the value of `x` needs to change in the calling shell, you must rewrite your code to avoid the pipeline.

One horrible-looking example:

```
# If you commit to one bash feature, may as well commit to them all:
#   Arithmetic compound: (( x-- > 0 ))
#   Process substitution: > >( cat )
while (( x-- > 0 )); do echo Loop $x; done > >( cat )
```

Comment: @udi, read about process substitution [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: @chepner, Thank you very much!  I had a little typo and now it works.