# Variable loses value after piped while loop

Tags: bash, shell

I'm pretty new to bash and I'm trying to find the process with odd pid and biggest memory usage, so I came up with:

```
maxpid=0; maxsize=0; ps -axl --no-headers | tr -s ' ' : | cut -d : -f 3,8 | while read proc; do pid=$((echo $proc | cut -d : -f 1)); psize=$((echo $proc | cut -d : -f 2));if(($pid % 2 == 1)); then if(($psize > $maxsize)); then maxsize=$psize; maxpid=$pid; fi; fi; done; echo "$maxpid $maxsize";
```

Which, with a bit of indentation, is:

```
maxpid=0; maxsize=0; 
ps -axl --no-headers | tr -s ' ' : | cut -d : -f 3,8 | 
while read proc; do                              (1)
    pid=$((echo $proc | cut -d : -f 1));         (2)
    psize=$((echo $proc | cut -d : -f 2));       (3)
    if(($pid % 2 == 1); then 
        if($psize > $maxsize); then 
            maxsize=$psize; 
            maxpid=$pid; 
        fi; 
    fi; 
done; 
echo "$maxpid $maxsize";
```

I need to run it from command line, so I don't want a bash script.
I know the two nested `if` are not so good, but I wasn't able to use logical AND.. I tried:

```
if(($pid % 2 -eq 1 -a $psize -gt $maxsize)); then
```

and also

```
if(($pid % 2 == 1 && $psize > $maxsize)); then
```

I also tried square brakets, but I'm not able to get it to work.
Any help and correction are widely appreciated.

EDIT: I was able to shorten rows (1), (2) and (3) into

```
while read -r pid psize; do
```

EDIT 2: with a little more debug, I was able to see that everything is working correctly inside the if body (which I corrected to `if (($pid % 2 ==1)) && (($psize > $maxsize)); then`, the vars `maxpid` and `maxsize` are correctly set, but then the last `echo` is printing "0 0".. Looks like I have a problem of synchronization

Comment: Your `while` loop is beeing executed in a child process due to pipes. Therefore, the changes of the environment of that child process, such as changes in the values of its variables `pid` and `psize`, are lost when the loop ends (`end` keyword). Read the last paragrahp in the section [**pipelines**](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Pipelines) of man manual pages

Comment: What can I add to make it work?

Comment: This is a classical problem. Read the following [solved question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667509/problem-accessing-a-global-variable-from-within-a-while-loop/4667725#4667725). I guess there must be many questions in this website about this issue.

Comment: easiest way to get info from loop out is echo it  (or save to file or somethin similarly boring)

Comment: Thank you @Jdamian