# Cumulative counting values from files

Tags: bash, grep, find

I need to extract numbers from several files into a cumulative variable and print that variable for each parent directory as shown

```
├───Parent1
│   ├───20210824_2000
│   │   ├───200000_child1
│   │   │       report.md
│   │   │       log.log
│   │   │       file.xml
│   │   │       input.json
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200030_child2
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200034_child3
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200039_child4
│   │   ...
│   ├───20210825_0800
│   │   ├───200000_child1
│   │   │       report.md
│   │   │       log.log
│   │   │       file.xml
│   │   │       input.json
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200030_child2
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200034_child3
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200039_child4
│   │   ...
│   ...
├───Parent2
│   ├───20210824_2000
│   │   ├───200000_child1
│   │   │       report.md
│   │   │       log.log
│   │   │       file.xml
│   │   │       input.json
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200030_child2
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200034_child3
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200039_child4
│   │   ...
│   ├───20210825_0800
│   │   ├───200000_child1
│   │   │       report.md
│   │   │       log.log
│   │   │       file.xml
│   │   │       input.json
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200030_child2
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200034_child3
│   │   │       
│   │   ├───200039_child4
│   │   ...
│   ...
...
```

I can't seem to extract the grep output into a numeric variable. The child folder has a timestamp attached so I sort since I only want the latest files.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type d -iname 'parent*' | while read -r dir; do
    sum=0;
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort -r | head -1 | 
    (
        while read -r subdir; do
            count="$(find "$subdir" -type f -iname '*report.md' -exec grep -ohP '(?<=\*)\d+(?=\*+ number of things)' {} \+)" 
            sum=$((sum + count))
        done
        basename "$dir" "$sum"
    )    
done
```

But this doesn't seem to want to add `count` to `sum` it rather just prints `count` to the console for each file.

Comment: [while-loop-subshell-dilemma-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/while-loop-subshell-dilemma-in-bash) ?

Comment: Wait... your Child directories have multiple directories in them? There's nothing in that image of your directory structure to suggest that (And why is it an image and not simple text? `tree(1)` is good for generating directory trees if you have it installed). Please update it to include examples of files you *don't* want included in the sum.

Comment: @Shawn Is that better?

Comment: @anubhava Does the tree answer your question too?

Comment: @Lety What do I do in the while loop then? The grep? So:
`while read -r subdir; do
 count="$(grep -ohP '(?<=\*)\d+(?=\*+ number of things)')" 
 sum=$((sum + count))
done < < $(find "$subdir" -type f -iname '*report.md')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem due to the sub shell that is created by each while, so variable are not global, you can find useful information in "[Shell variables set inside while loop not visible outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667509/shell-variables-set-inside-while-loop-not-visible-outside-of-it)"

Also count variable could have problem because find should returns multiple line.

Try with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type d -iname 'parent*' | while read -r dir; do
    sum=0;
    while read -r subdir; do    
       while read report; do 
            count="$(grep -ohP '(?<=\*)\d+(?=\*+ number of things)' $report)" 
            sum=$((sum + count))
       done < <(find "$subdir" -type f -iname '*report.md')
    done < <(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort -r | head -1)
    folder=$(basename $dir)
    echo "$folder $sum"
done
```

Pay attention to the spaces in `done < <(`.

I have not tested, sorry.